# What are 'Magics' in Database and When to Use Them

Tags: database, oracle

I've seen a lot of article mentioning these 'Magics' like 'Magic Tables', 'Magic Columns', 'Magic Number', etc. What are they, really? Please give a concise explanation and example for these 'magics'.

[Edit]

The link below says that rownum is a magic column

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Is it a general term?

Comment: Could you share a few links to these articles about "magics" in Oracle ?

Comment: @kordirko, I had the question edited

Comment: `RWONUM` pseudocolumn is explained in detail in the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm Please specify what is unclear to you about `rownum` ?

Comment: `rownum` is not a "magic" column. It's a documented "pseudocolumn": https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: But, the article I mentioned above says that "ROWNUM is a magic column in Oracle Database that gets many people into trouble". Now I'm getting more confused -_- @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Logos I think Tom meant "magic" as in "it does something behind-the-scenes that you don't get to see/be in charge of; you only see the results". That Arthur C. Clarke quote seems apropos here: `Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that the text is just using a metaphoric expression but there is a very similar term in programming called [Magic Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string) and [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). You can see in the wikipedia there are several meanings.

I personally think on the meaning of:

> Unique values with unexplained meaning or multiple occurrences which
>   could (preferably) be replaced with named constants

This means that it is better to write:

```
for(int = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++){
```

Than

```
for(int = 0; i < 20; i++){
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325478/16206) stackoverflow answer for more information why magic numbers/strings is an anti-pattern